# angular flask websocket not connecting

Tags: angular, flask, websocket

backend (flask):

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

    # Define a custom WebSocket event handler
    @socketio.on('connect')
    def handle_connect():
        print('WebSocket client connected')

    # Define a custom WebSocket event handler for a custom event
    @socketio.on('my_event')
    def handle_my_event(data):
        print('Received custom event: ' + data)
        emit('my_response', 'Server received: ' + data, broadcast=True)


    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

frontend (angular)

```
  public connect(): Observable<any> {
    this.socket$ = new WebSocketSubject('ws://127.0.0.1:5000');
    return this.socket$.asObservable()
  }
```

for some reason frontend cant connect to backend via websocket. Only thing i see in backend console is

(8280) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 46326)
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2023 15:39:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 359 0.001002

but when i try to connect to ws with this script it works as intended.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.1.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:5000');  // Connect to the /test namespace

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('WebSocket connected to /test namespace');
            // Send a custom event to the server after the WebSocket connection is established
            socket.emit('my_event', 'Hello, Server!');
        });

        socket.on('my_response', function(data) {
            console.log('Received response from server:', data);
        });
    </script>
```

why cant angular connect to ws even though its a tutorial code

Answer (score 0):

#### Websockets != socketio

I think you are misunderstanding something here. SocketIO is a libarary built on top of websockets. You can't just simply open up a websocket to a SocketIO application, but that's exactly what you are doing in your angular example code. In your other "plain js" example you are using the socketio library to make your connection, which is fundamentally different than the other approach.

I would suggest that you install the [`socket.io-client` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) in your angular project and then use the socketio implementation provided by that.